# What's with the crossed out trophy icon?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I started the Computer Savvy challenge and, a few rooms into the run, I noticed a pretty weird icon:

[image: enter link description here]

What does it mean?

Comment: Which icon are you talking about in the image?

Comment: FWIW I saw that icon when I was trying the Pitch Black challenge.

Comment: @DwarfSlice The one below the key count.

Comment: -1 for no free-hand circle.

Comment: I never unlocked items or achievements (for example, completing the caves without taking damage) when playing the challenges. I believe this icon is a visual indication that these are disabled in the current run.

Comment: maybe an indication that you are playing an incompleted challenge? Just a guess though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That icon means that the run won't count for achievements and item unlocks. The same icon is present in any run where you put in the seed manually: that's because some seeds/challenges give you an advantage in terms of drops, item combinations and treasure rooms, while normally the runs are completely randomized.