# Challenge run or normal run?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I just came back to a run in progress after a fairly long break and forgot if the current run is a challenge or not. Is there any way I can check that? I don't feel like continuing the run but I also don't want to forfeit a challenge run with this many floors done.

Comment: Challenges and seeded runs have a [special icon](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/190557/whats-with-the-crossed-out-trophy-icon) that shows on the screen.  Mainly because you can't use them to unlock things (i.e. it doesn't count towards unlocking ???, It Lives, The Polaroid, or The Negative)

Comment: @Powerlord that seems like an answer to me :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Challenge runs have a small icon in the same place you can find the hard mode icon if you're playing on hard mode. The crossed-out trophy icon indicates that you can't earn item unlocks or achievements, and can also be found on runs where you manually input a seed. So this icon won't be a 100% guarantee that you're on challenge mode, but it's as close as you're likely to get.

[image: challenge run icon]

Comment: Alternatively, work out if the item setup leads to something absurd. If so, probably a challenge run ;)