# Does a seeded run in The Binding of Isaac count for the D6 unlock?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth, the-binding-of-isaac-repentance

I've only beat Mom's Heart three times, and I need to beat it another 8 times in order to get Blue Baby to aim for the D6 unlock. Can a seeded run still count as one of my runs towards it?

I know the 11th run that should be the one to unlock Blue Baby won't unlock him if it's seeded, but what about the other runs that lead up to it? Can I use seeds up to that last run and then beat a non-seeded one last to unlock Blue Baby? Or will those seeded ones not count at all as 7 Mom's Heart defeats, and I just wasted my time?

I'm playing on the Nintendo Switch.

Answer (score 7):

Any run that has the "blocked achievement" icon won't be counted towards any in-game achievement.

- Found items won't be recorded in the archive
- donation machines won't be available
- mobs/boss kill won't be counted
- etc

Unlocks are tied to an achievement, so if you can't get the achievement you can't get the unlock.

In order to maintain the game balance (or more correctly "to keep the game horribly luck based") most seeds will disable achievements so that you can't just play a run that gives you magneto, brimstone and ludvico on level one. You can easily know this by looking at the corresponding icon in the hud:

[image]
(reusing the image [from this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/191414))

Notice that not every seed will disable achievement: some of the special seeds in the game will still allow you to play normally.
As a general rule these special seeds tend to be those who only have cosmetic effects (like "H0H0 H0H0" which gives Isaac a Santa hat) or those that actually make your experience even more miserable than before (example "D0NT ST0P", which damages you whenever you stop moving)

Answer (score 1):

No, seeded runs don't count for almost anything. Especially not for what you want: killing mom N times.

Sources:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/bindingofisaac/comments/2m7zns/if_i_kill_moms_heart_on_a_seeded_run_does_it/
- https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/204247-the-binding-of-isaac-afterbirth-plus/75236221
- https://steamcommunity.com/app/250900/discussions/0/604941528485717742/
- https://steamcommunity.com/app/250900/discussions/0/451850468375054240/